# Inequality in the sense of distributions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, schwartz-space

What does

$$
f\leq g
$$
mean for two Schwartz distributions/generalized functions $f $ and $g$? I assume it means that the inequality holds when tested with positive functions. The next question would then be: if such an inequality holds, is it always true that $g-f$ is a positive "proper" function ( $\in L^1_{loc}$) or measure ?

Comment: If $f\ge0$ then it can be represented as a measure. Reference: Hormander 'The Analysis of Partial Differential Operators - Vol 1' Thm 2.1.7

Comment: For $u \in C^0_c(K)$ take a sequence of test functions $\phi_n$ decreasing to $u$. Then $f(\phi_n)$ is decreasing and $\ge 0$ thus it converges, and choosing $\phi_0 = 2\|u\|_\infty \chi_K$ ($\chi_K$ a $C^\infty_c$ approximation of $1_K$) we have $|f(\phi_n)|\le |f(\chi_K)|2 \|u\|_\infty$ thus $f$ is a measure @daw

Comment: @reuns if you turn this into an answer, I will accept it